# Understanding the Float conversion behaviour of pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, floating-point, type-conversion, precision

When I convert the python float 77422223.0 to a spark FloatType, I get 77422224. If I do so with DoubleType I get 77422223. How is this conversion working and is there a way to compute when such an error will happen?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([77422223.0],FloatType())
display(df)
```

output

[image]

and as expected running

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([77422223.0],DoubleType())
display(df)
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Suppose I tell you you can have three places past the decimal.  That means you can exactly represent 1234.567, and 1234.568, but not 1234.5678.  Suppose I tell you you can have seven significant digits, *total*.  That means you can exactly represent 1234.567, and 12345.67, and 123456.7.  You can even represent 1234567.0.  But you cannot represent 12345678.0!  That requires eight significant digits, and I said you could only have seven.  So you can represent 12345670.0, or 12345680.0, but nothing in between.

Comment: Computer floating point uses binary, not decimal, and there's a limit on the number of significant *bits* you can have, but the overarching principle is the same.  The number 77422223 converted to binary requires 27 bits.  That's more precision than single-precision floating point can typically hold: the maximum precision for that type is typically 24 bits.  So you can represent 77422216.0, or 77422224.0, but nothing in between.

Comment: But *double* precision floating point has up to 53 bits of precision, so it can exactly represent 77422223.0 just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this conversion working…

I assume the Spark `FloatType` is IEEE-754 binary32. This format uses a 24-bit significand and an exponent range from −126 to +127. Each number is represented as a sign and a 24-bit numeral with a “.” after its first digit multiplied by two to the power of an exponent, such as +1.01001100001111100000000<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>13</sup>.

In binary, 77,422,223 is 100100111010101111010001111<sub>2</sub>. That is 27 bits. So it cannot be represented in the binary32 format. When it is converted to the binary32 format, the conversion operating rounds it to the nearest representable value. That is 100100111010101111010010000<sub>2</sub>, which has 23 significant digits.

> … and is there a way to compute when such an error will happen?

When the number is written in binary, if the number of bits from the first 1 to its last 1, including both of those, is more than 24, then it cannot be represented in the binary32 format.

Also, if the magnitude of the number is less than 2<sup>−126</sup>, it cannot be represented in binary32 unless it is a multiple of 2<sup>−149</sup>, including zero. Numbers in this range are subnormal and have a fixed exponent −126, and the lowest bit of the significand has a position value of 2<sup>−149</sup>. And, if the magnitude number is 2<sup>128</sup> or greater, it cannot be represented, unless it is +∞ or −∞.